# Why am I getting this when I do a NSLog?

Tags: ios6, nslog

This is the line of code for my NSLog:

```
    NSLog(@"\n\noCLientFirstName: %@\nlastName: %@\nconcatenatedName: %@",oClientFirstName, lastName, concatenatedName);
```

Why am I getting output that looks like this?

```
oCLientFirstName: <UITextField: 0xefe0330; frame = (394 293; 160 30); text = 'Bob'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xefe12d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xefe0120>>

lastName: <UITextField: 0xef05bd0; frame = (20 40; 260 40); text = 'Jones'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xef057c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xef05ba0>>

concatenatedName: Bob<UITextField: 0xef05bd0; frame = (20 40; 260 40); text = 'Jones'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xef057c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xef05ba0>>
```

I have NEVER had this issue before; the output should look like this:

```
oClientFirstName: Bob
lastName: Jones
concatenatedName: BobJones
```

What's going on?

Comment: Why shouldn't you be getting this?

Comment: I found it... passing UITextField rather than NSString... I'm going to give you the points if you will reword your comment as an answer.

Comment: That's very kind of you to offer and I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are passing `UITextField` objects to your log function rather than NSStrings. Double check the types and adjust your code accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

%@ format specifier in NSLog will call the following methods in order on the object parameter for the position. 
debugDescription
description

You're getting the result of that for the objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"\n\noCLientFirstName: %@\nlastName: %@\nconcatenatedName: %@",oClientFirstName.text, lastName.text, concatenatedName.text);
```

this is the solution of your question :)